# How to get visitors count in one of the joomla article page using IP Address

Tags: php, joomla1.5

How to get visitors count in one of the joomla article page using IP Address. I know there is a hits count in every article page in joomla. But its increasing the count every load, so its not useful,also there is lot of extensions available for website visitors count, but in my case I need visitors count for only one article. Any advice please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics is incredibly detailed, and would allow you narrow down results down to a single page, giving you the data you require.

Whilst you could technically apply that to a single page via a module, it would make more sense to collect data from the whole site and then use the analytics interface to find the data you are after.  That way should you decide you need the data from other pages further on down the line, it will also be available.

You could add their code to your template at templates/your-template/index.php, or I'm sure many plug-ins are available to do this for you.

Comment: Really thanks for your information. its very helpful!! Is it possible to display the visitors count form the Google Analytics in my website?

Comment: I am using Joomla version 1.5

Comment: Analytics has an api, so it should be technically possible.  Not sure if any pre-written extensions are doing this, though.